# How to find cell row iteration after empty row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

please help me,

i want loop spreadsheet with apps script in column A, but in cell row 1 until 10 cell is empty, how to defined first cell after empty cell? in this case its cell in row 11

Comment: I think that providing your current script will help users think of the issue and solution. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 1):

You can get row 11 if you use getDataRange function.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange

It is a sample below.

```
function main() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues();
  Logger.log(values);
}
```